# How to connect to local KVM guest via SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, kvm-switch

I use Virt-manager for virtualization on Debian. I want to connect to my guest through a remote SSH tunnel. Guest is also on local Debian machine. Is this possible?

I have already tried this command found [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/how-to-use-vnc-with-ssh-tunnel-is-this-howto-secure):

```
ssh -f -L 5900:localhost:5900 USERNAME@REMOTE-PC-B-PUBLIC-IPADDRESS -N -p 22
```

However, I get this message:

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 5901
Could not request local forwarding.
```

So I changed the local port to this.

```
ssh -f -L 5920:localhost:5900 USERNAME@REMOTE-PC-B-PUBLIC-IPADDRESS -N -p 22
```

It seems to be working. There is no error message.

Now I use Vinagre to connect to the guest with `localhost:5900`. And the window is showing up.

Is the traffic still going through the SSH tunnel?

[image: window]

In Vinagre there is also a filed for adding a SSH host. However, when I enter the domain/IP there it will prompt the password. If I type it in every time the connection get closed. Any suggestion for that?

Do I have to use Spice or VNC option?

I Googleed since two days to get this fixed.

So I am interessted in how other people create an encrypted SSH tunnel between local machine and (local) guest machine and how do they connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

> So I am interested in how other people create an encrypted SSH tunnel between local machine and (local) guest machine and how do they connect to it.

It really depends on what is the use case. You just posted some command, but without any information *where* do you run it, which is quite crucial. So let me get it straight. You have `GUEST` machine and `HOST` machine on the same network (basically virtual one). You can `ping` and `ssh` from one to another. And there comes two possibilities:

- Run *local* port forwarding from `HOST` machine:

  ```
  ssh -f -L 5920:localhost:5900 GUEST_USER@GUEST_IP -N
  ```
- Run *remote* port forwarding from `GUEST` machine:

  ```
  ssh -f -R 5920:localhost:5900 HOST_USER@HOST_IP -N
  ```

And then connect using your software to the `localhost`, port `5920` (you put there 5900 as from the screenshot) and all traffic to this port should be forwarded to the `GUEST` port `5900`.

---

But anyway, I don't think this is needed. If you want to establish Host-Guest connection, you are never leaving the virtual network and there should be no need to do *expensive* encryption. You should be able to connect directly to `GUEST-IP:5900` if the service is listening on external IP.

Comment: connect directly to `GUEST-IP` with `SSH`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use virt-viewer?

virt-viewer --connect qemu+ssh://root@KVM_HOST:22/system VM_NAME

Then there is no need to mess around with ssh tunnels

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ssh key is on the host of your vm (on above example on 172.18.10.184)!
Some extension if your tuneling is needed

In my case, I did a ssh port forwarding as the host of my vm is not directly accessible from the web

`ssh -L 10023:172.18.10.184:22 myPlaceToGo -p2222`

and then

`virt-viewer --connect qemu+ssh://myUsr@localhost:10023/system 2`

some `ssh -10023 myPlaceToGo` should work without prompting for password